# Puppy Pee Schedule: If not relieved post mealtime, will it lead to a UTI?

Tags: dogs, urination, biology, junior-pets, urinary-tract-disease

My partner has cautioned me that if we don't take our 6 month old puppy outside to pee within 30 minutes after mealtime, he's at risk for developing an urinary tract infection!

I've searched all combinations of "uti" "housetraining" "puppy" and "post mealtime", etc., and I can't seem to find anything that even gestures to this risk. Can you help point me in a direction that explains this?

(As far as I can tell [a bacteria of some kind must be present for a urinary tract *infection* to take place](https://www.akc.org/expert-advice/health/urinary-tract-infections-uti-in-dogs/).)

Answer (score 1):

A UTI is a bacterial infection. While holding urine doesn’t necessarily cause a UTI, it will keep and build up any bacteria that have made their way into a urinary tract, if the urine is not released. Plus, it’s not healthy for a dog to be forced to hold its urine.

It is important to take a puppy out to pee frequently because:

- Puppies need to pee more frequently than adult dogs
- It helps train them to understand that need to pee
- It keeps them from having an accident inside
- It prevents discomfort for the dog

30 minutes isn’t necessarily a hard and fast rule, but many dogs prefer (or are in the habit of) using the bathroom after eating. If anything, your partner’s rule is more likely to prevent an accident in your house than a UTI for your puppy.